# How to find the range of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2 - x}$

I found:
Domain, $x \in$ $R - \{0, 1\}$

But I am struggling to find range of this fucntion.

My approach to find the range:
$y = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^2 - x}$
$\Rightarrow yx^2 -yx - 1 = 0$

After this I used Discriminant rule:
$D \ge 0$
$\Rightarrow D = y^2 +4y \ge 0$

From above, I got, $y > 0 \space$ or $\space y \in (0, \infty)$

But I am unable to find the rest part of the range.

On Internet, I found Range of the above function as, $y \in$ $(-\infty, -4] \space \cup \space (0, \infty)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Based on the desmos graph it appears to be (0,$\infty$) $\cup$ (-$\infty$,-4]

Comment: $y^2+4y\ge 0\Leftrightarrow y(y+4)\ge 0 \Leftrightarrow y\le-4$ or $y\ge0$. But don’t forget to check whether $x^2-x$ is not $0$.

Comment: @Aig how did you get $y \le -4$?

Comment: @RajIshu The product of two numbers ($y$ and $y+4$, in our case) is non-negative if and only if they are of the same sign. So either $y$ and $y+4$ both $\ge 0$, or both $\le 0$.

Comment: @Aig Ohh yes. Now I understood. Thank You.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you can define $t= x^2-x$. Now observe that $t\in[-\frac14, \infty)$ and the problem is boiled down to finding range of $f(t)=\frac1t$ where $t\in[-\frac14, \infty) \text{ and } t\neq0$.

Comment: @Aig I will suggest to write your comment as an answer, so that the question does not remains in the unanswered section (see e.g. [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) post in meta )

Comment: @Marco ok, I will do that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us find the range of the function $f(x)=\frac1{x^2-x}$. The domain of this function is indeed $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}$. Now let us determine all such values of $y$ that there exists $x$ in $D$ such that $$y=\frac1{x^2-x}.$$

Since $x\ne 0$ or $1$, it is equivalent to the equation with respect to $x$: $$yx^2-yx-1=0.$$

If $y=0$ then the equality doesn’t hold.

If $y\ne0$ then this is a quadratic equation. Since $0$ and $1$ are not its solutions, its solutions are always in $D$. It has solutions if and only if its discriminant is non-negative. So $$y^2+4y\ge0$$ $$y(y+4)\ge 0$$ $$y\le -4\text{ or }y\ge 0.$$

Removing $y=0$, we get that the range of $f$ is $$(-\infty,-4]\cup(0,\infty).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. $D\ge 0,$ and $y \ne 0$ (Why?)
2. $y^2+4y \ge 0$. or $(y+2)^2 \ge 4;$

Can you finish?